# RedBlackTree Mark Allen Weis Remove(x) Top Bottom Approach

Tags: java, red-black-tree

From the original Mark Allen Weis RedBlackTree implementation from [Data Structures and Problem Solving Using Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321541405) found [here](http://pastebin.com/Gg3YbPUg).

I cannot seem to get my head around the removal of a node from the tree. After reading the [wikipedia resource](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) I noticed "is_leaf()" function.. the problem with this and Mark Weis implementation is there is no way to tell which node is a leaf and which isn't

```
void delete_one_child(struct node *n)
{
    /*
     * Precondition: n has at most one non-null child.
     */
    struct node *child = is_leaf(n->right) ? n->left : n->right;

    replace_node(n, child);
    if (n->color == BLACK) {
            if (child->color == RED)
                    child->color = BLACK;
            else
                    delete_case1(child);
    }
    free(n);
}
```

Is_Leaf java implementation

```
public boolean isLeaf(){
if(left == null && right == null){
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Console Output

```
value=1 color=1 leaf=true left=null right=14
value=2 color=1 leaf=true left=null right=5
value=5 color=0 leaf=true left=null right=null
value=7 color=0 leaf=true left=2 right=11
value=8 color=0 leaf=true left=null right=null
value=11 color=1 leaf=true left=8 right=null
value=14 color=1 leaf=true left=7 right=15
value=15 color=1 leaf=true left=null right=null
```

Tree format (From Console)

```
└── (1) 1
    └── (1) 14
        ├── (0) 7
        │   ├── (1) 2
        │   │   └── (0) 5
        │   └── (1) 11
        │       └── (0) 8
        └── (1) 15
```

Rules:

1. The root is black
2. Every red node has a black parent
3. Any children of a red node are black
   – A red node cannot have red children
4. Every path from the root to a leaf contains the same number
   of black nodes

So my question is how do I implement the removal from [this](http://pastebin.com/Gg3YbPUg) implementation of Red and Back Trees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to implement isLeaf()?  If so you should be passing isLeaf the node you want to check.

```
public boolean isLeaf(RedBlackNode<AnyType> t ){
if(t.left == null && t.right == null){
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Otherwise, the algorithm itself looks right, the only real work is translating C into Java which is easy.

Comment: Also I noticed this in your insert:     if( current != nullNode )
            throw new DuplicateItemException( item.toString( ) );
        current = new RedBlackNode<AnyType>( item, nullNode, nullNode ); 

I think you probably want to check that current.element != nullNode.element since the value of nullNode is set, and I think it might be why you appear to be inserting duplicate items.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the correct isLeaf() code:

```
public boolean isLeaf(RedBlackNode<AnyType> t ){
    if(t.left.element == null && t.right.element == null){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No.  The criteria for a leaf is that its left and right node *pointers* are null, i.e. they don't reference other nodes underneath them. If left or right are null, your code will throw an exception because it's trying to access properties of null elements.

Comment: @matthewdavidson That sure doesn't look right when looking at the insert() code. In the insert code, when it creates a new "leaf" node it uses this line: "current = new RedBlackNode<AnyType>( item, nullNode, nullNode );" which creates a new node with non-null pointers for left and right. That is why you have to check the element fields of those pointers.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but a leaf is not a node.  That is the point I am making.  'current' is a node, not a leaf.  'left' and 'right' are leaves.  A node sits in between the head and the leaves, and its left and right pointers refer to either a node, a leaf or nothing.  A leaf is on the end with pointers leading to nothing.  Look at the way the code behaves in the tests above. The left and right pointers of leaves always point to null, and their elements are NOT null.

Comment: @Justin can you take a look at my remove method for RedBlackTree? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705454/how-to-fix-remove-in-redblacktree-implementation

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for `nullnode` instead of `null`:

```
public boolean isLeaf() {
    if(left == nullnode && right == nullnode) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I've recently modified my question, can you please update your question accordingly? thank you!

Comment: Can you take a look at my red black tree remove method? It's similar to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705454/how-to-fix-remove-in-redblacktree-implementation